# "if talks were successful" VS "if talks are successful"

Tags: tense

> 1. If the talks **were** successful between China and the US, they **could** lead to discussions in Washington, D.C., between senior officials of both countries.
> 2. If the talks **are** successful between China and the US, they **will** lead to discussions in Washington, D.C., between senior officials of both countries.

When talking about possible things, which tense should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sentences are not parallel although both are valid. The one expresses certainty; the other probability. So it is not a matter of tense, but of what is intended.

In the first sentence, the implication is that there are no such talks. It is a counter-factual statement. The speaker suggests that if such talks were held, they might or might well lead to discussions in DC. If such talks are on-going, it makes no sense to phrase them in the past tense. We are talking about possibilities.

In the second sentence, it is clear that there are such talks, and a spurious certainty is expressed about them. I say spurious because the "will" implying certainty is contingent upon success, and no indication about the probability of success is presented. Indeed, it may be that the speaker defines "success" in this situation as being the holding of talks. In that case, it is a fancy way of saying the truism "It will definitely be a success if it is a success."

Comment: {In the first sentence, the implication is that there are no such talks. } Do you mean there are no talk at all, be is successful or not, Or do you mean there are talk, but the talks are not going well?

Comment: My point is that we use the past tense to suggest either past time or counter-factuals. "If I went to New York City, I'd take I-80" implies that I am not currently intending to go to NYC. If the intention was to discuss past talks that were not successful, we would say, "If the talks had been successful, they could have lead." So sentence 1 suggests no current talks. Sentence 2 suggests current talks. Sorry that I was not clear before.